# Setting ESP-IDF Component directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp-idf, espressif-idf

I'm using ESP-IDF extension for Visual Studio Code. I create new project by choosing template, but what does `ESP-IDF Component directory` means? What I should put there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The  IDF build system assembles a firmware from a number of different components. E.g. the gpio system, the http server, etc. are all components. I assume this VSCode configuration is the equivalent of the [`EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIR`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#optional-project-variables) build variable that indicates where the build system should search for components. The components comprising the IDF don't require configuration, but other components you use may.